# Update STM32 firmware via Android

Tags: stm32, android, firmware

Sorry for the very open question, but I really know nothing about EE.

I am an Android developer,

I have been asked to create an Android application to update the firmware of a STM32 microcontroller.

Please can somebody give me some hints of how to go about it?

Comment: This is far too broad as is. Can you narrow it down to a specific problem?

Comment: @Null I agree Null, it's very broad :-( the point is that I have posted this question with the purpose of trying to narrow down the problem, since really I have no idea of how to accomplish that...

Comment: You should probably consult with an EE. One person in an afternoon will be able to help you a lot more than we can in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my personal experience, there are 3 methods to program the flash of STM32 series.

1. Using JTAG. This require you have a JTAG emulator and your Android device has a USB host interface.
2. Using STM32's built-in "bootloader", STM32 have a built-in bootloader, which supports various interfaces, such as USART, SPI, CAN, USB, I2C. These don't need emulator, you only need to implement these hardware interfaces. On your Android side, i think the USB (host) is a "must-have" one? Right? For these methods, you may refer to their relevant protocol manual at "http://www.st.com/stonline/stappl/resourceSelector/app?page=fullResourceSelector&doctype=application_note&SubClassID=1169", you can search docs with these word "XXX protocol used in the STM32 bootloader".
3. You need first burn a small "bootloader" (your own, not the built-in one), then this "bootloader" receive the new main firmware from a master, then you have even many interface choices, such as Ethernet,.... This is just like Android system's update method. But this maybe a little complicated.

Whichever method you select, you do need relevant hardware interface on your Android side, and read STM32's datasheet, reference manual, and learn the related protocol.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer diverger. Supposing I want to use the approach **2)** over **USART** what kind of hardware do you suggest I should get for testing purposes (cheapest)

Comment: 1). Your target board (the board/device with STM32 chip) should has the relevant USART port exported, there are several USART on STM32 chip, only **designated** ones support boot. You should google "STM32 system memory boot mode” (AN2606)" to decide which one to use. 2). On your Android device side, you also need a USART port (RS232 is enough, basically, it only need GND, Rx, Tx, 3 wires). 4). In code stage, you may refer to http://code.google.com/p/stm32flash/, it's a app programming STM32 using USART, in C.